# Как сделать такую логику на WP

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на WP, тип - визитка, имеет 30 товаров, поэтому смысл грузить WooCommerce нету. ( при заказе просто форма). Так вот. Есть страница со всеми товарами и при клике на товар его информация. Думаю сделать так. Сам товаров выводить как запись, а вот страница товар, не знаю как с точки зрение логики. Как лучше всего реализовать что бы было семантично, правильно, удобно?

Comment: Сделайте тип записей "Товары", где каждая запись - товар. В итоге будет архив со всеми товарами, где будете выводить краткую информацию (заголовок, картинка и тд.), а при нажатии переход на карточку товара с полным описанием. Так и правильно, в рамках WP ничего другого придумывать не надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно будет использовать как минимум следующие плагины:

- CPT UI (Custom Post Type User Interface) - для создания типа записи "Товары" slug желательно делать "product"
- ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) - позволит вам добавить необходимые поля атрибутов в товаре и всякие мелочи;
- Contact Form 7 - для создания формы обратной связи;

Этого вполне достаточно, ну а там уже по мелочи:

- Cyr-To-Lat Enhanced - транслитерация урлов;
- Huge IT Lightbox - для открытия картинок во всплывающем окне;
- SEO Yoast - для управления мета контентом.

Больше думаю не стоит, но там уже на ваше усмотрение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В итоге получите что-то вроде этого http://ugplitka.com.ua/ (не для рекламы)

Comment: Это сайт по продаже тротуарной плитки, у которого порядка 20-25 наименований. Поэтому WooСommerce там тоже не ставили - нет смысла

Comment: Для реализации запрошенной логики ни один плагин не обязателен. Все можно сделать своим кодом, и его совсем немного. Если делать через плагины - ок, CPT UI. Остальные не имеют вообще никакого отношения к вопросу.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что человек задающий такой вопрос сделает это своими руками. Остальное приведено как рекомендации, никто не говорил, что это обязательно. Развернутый ответ снимает много лишних вопросов.

Comment: Дословно «при заказе просто форма» CF7 не относится к вопросу? Вывод цены и дополнительных атрибутов не упростит человеку жизнь при использовании ACF?

Comment: Евгений спасибо большое за такой ответ. Да это именно то что я искал.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте тип записей "Товары", где каждая запись - товар. В итоге будет архив со всеми товарами, где будете выводить краткую информацию (заголовок, картинка и тд.), а при нажатии переход на карточку товара с полным описанием. Так и правильно, в рамках WP ничего другого придумывать не надо.